# How to make system calls cross-platform: maintainable and best practice

Tags: c, cross-platform

I have hundreds of system calls like this:

```c
char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

// ...

sprintf(buffer,"cat cgx_tmp.fbl >> cgx_tmp2.fbl");
system(buffer);
sprintf(buffer,"mv -f cgx_tmp2.fbl %s.fbl", datin);
system(buffer);
sprintf(buffer,"rm -f cgx_tmp.fbl");
system(buffer);
```

To fix the code, i.e. to make the system calls cross-platform, hundreds of OS-specific system calls like `mv`, `rm`, and `cat` might be modified like this:

```c
#ifdef WIN32
    sprintf (buffer, "move /y \"%s\" \"%s.fbb\"", datin, setname );
#else
    sprintf (buffer, "mv %s %s.fbb", datin, setname );
#endif
```

## Question

I just thought I'd ask before actually fixing the code. Is the above  `#ifdef` approach acceptable? Is there any best practice to consider system calls for Windows OS or any other platforms?

If any other approaches are preferred, it would be great if you give some examples of them. So that I can use them as a reference for my fix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please note that the term "system call" is not really about the `system` function, but about OS-level calls. Calls to the operating *system*.

Comment: And please note that there are actual *system* calls in every operating system that does some of the things you do. But like the commands you try to run, they are not portable either. If you want to work on both Unix and Unix-like systems, as well as on Windows, your best bet is to make a platform independent API which you can use, and which does all the dirty stuff with preprocessor conditional compilation. Or find an existing cross-platform library which already does it all for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right, thanks. It makes sense: *your best bet is to make a platform independent API which you can use, and which does all the dirty stuff with preprocessor conditional compilation.*

Comment: Using `system()` for renaming/removing/copying files etc. is wrong in the first place. Use [`remove`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html), [`rename`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) etc.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Are those available on Windows OS too? Just double-checking...

Comment: The question is not "Windows OS" but compilers that generate code for Windows OS. Yes, both `remove()` and `rename()` are available in my ancient MS C compiler. If you're planning this project, you should familiarise yourself with what's available before starting work on the project.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Right, I'm doing my homework :)

Comment: @Megidd yes, they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of the circumstances when I consider `C` source files inclusion correct.

Have two or more files with commands for a particular system and include them

```
#if defined(WIN32)
#include "win.c"
#else
#include "linux.c"
#endif
```